# How to use server side includes with browser-sync

Tags: node.js

I have some static files which use server side includes (SSI). Those files have .shtml extension. I'm currently using a local apache in the development cycle.
I want to replace that with [browser-sync](http://www.browsersync.io).

How do I enable SSI?

I found a module called [browsersync-ssi](https://www.npmjs.org/package/browsersync-ssi), but it's unclear how to use it with the browser-sync command line, installed via npm-install.

Answer (score 1):

there are 2 options to use browser-sync with SSI. my browserync-ssi module depends on node-ssi which does not support all SSI features. the "if"- directive is also not stable.

I would only suggest to use it if you can be sure only to use the base features of SSI. includes for example.

another option is to use browser-syncs proxy feature. http://www.browsersync.io/docs/options/#option-proxy
your apache would still run in the background. so its not an actual replacement but a good solution in your case to benefit from browser-sync.

if you just need features like that from SSI but the not the technology and syntax itself I would suggest to switch to another templating engine like ejs or nunjucks as a [browser-sync] middleware.
for example: https://github.com/soenkekluth/browser-sync-ejs